# Recursively generating a list of n factorial in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am having trouble implementing this in Python. I want to write a function with (sole) input n, that recursively generates a list of factorial values 1! ... n!

So far I have thought of storing the recursively derived values of n-factorial in a variable, and then adding (pushing?) them into a list. The question I have is how do I 'save' the list? I am not sure how to check if a list exists or not as well...

```
def recFactorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
        print(l)
    else:
        l = []
        f = n * recFactorial(n-1)
        if l:
            l = l.push(f)
        else:
            l = []
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this with recursion? Is it an assignment?

Comment: It's not an assignment, it's part of an (ungraded) workshop. I understand recursion, but I don't know how to implement a recursive list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive function calls can't see the local variables of the other calls to the same function. If you want several calls to be able to work with the same list, the list needs to either be a parameter or a return value of the function (or I suppose a global variable, but that would be really bad design).

In this case, I think it would be easiest to pass the list as the return value of the function. It would be created in the base case, where you'd return the trivial list `[1]`. Each outer call would append a value to the list (and use the last value that was on it previously to do their calculation).

```
def recFactorialList(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]   # base case, still returns a list

    lst = recFactorialList(n-1)
    n_fac = lst[-1] * n   # use the last value to calculate a new value
    lst.append(n_fac)   # add n factorial to the end of the list
    return lst   # return the updated list
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are facing  troubles local variables in recursion, I would suggest you add a wrapper function. What about the below one?

```
def fact_wrapper(n):
    lst = [1]
    def fact(n):
        if n == 0 or n==1:
            return 1
        else:
            a = n * fact(n-1)
            lst.append(a)
            return a

    fact(n)
    return lst


print(fact_wrapper(5))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

If recursion is not that much important, you may write a simple generator:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
       result *= i
       yield result
```

Then,

```
print list(factorial(5))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Or, you can use `next()` also to evaluate values lazily. If you aren't familiar with python generator, you may see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Comment: This guy doesn't seem to be familiar with generators. You could possibly show him an example of how to use one.

Answer (score 3):

The crucial things missing from your code are:

1. Since you want the function to return a list the base case (n==1) needs to return a list, as Blckknght explains in his answer.
2. The non-base case (n>1) needs to return something too! It's a very common bug when writing recursive code to neglect to return something from every execution path.

---

This version is a recursive generator. It doesn't return a list, it's an iterable that generates the factorial values one at a time, but it's easy to capture those in a list if you want.

```
def gen_factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        yield 1
    else:
        for u in gen_factorial(n - 1):
            yield u
        yield u * n

for u in gen_factorial(5):
    print(u)

print(list(gen_factorial(8)))
```

**output**

```
1
2
6
24
120
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320]
```