# Find factorial of a list of numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, math, factorial

I have a set of numbers:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I wish to create a function that calculates the factorial of each number in the set and prints it.

```
input_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
fact = 1
for item in input_set:
    for number in range(1,item+1):
        fact = fact * number
    print ("Factorial of", item, "is", fact)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Factorial of 1 is 1
Factorial of 2 is 2
Factorial of 3 is 12
Factorial of 4 is 288
Factorial of 5 is 34560
```

Which is obviously wrong. 
I would really like to know what is wrong with my code and how to fix it.

**Note:** I don't wish to use the `math.factorial` function for this code.

Comment: input_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. This is not a list but a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively generating a list of n factorial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560108/recursively-generating-a-list-of-n-factorial-in-python)

Comment: input_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} this is not a list or dictionary

Comment: Girl you are right! you just misplaced variable it's just long to explain in comment so posted answer. check it out.

Answer (score 6):

set `fact=1` inside for loop.

```
input_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
for item in input_set:
    fact = 1
    for number in range(1,item+1):
        fact = fact * number
        print ("Factorial of", input, "is", fact)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def factorial(n):

    fact = 1

    for factor in range(1, n + 1):
        fact *= factor

    return fact

>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> my_factorials = [factorial(x) for x in my_list]
>>> my_factorials
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset fact before the second for loop, it's just multiplying with the result of the previous factorial.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a built-in `factorial()` in `math` module.

```
from math import factorial

def factorialize(nums):
    """ Return factorials of a list of numbers. """

    return [factorial(num) for num in nums]

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for index, fact in enumerate(factorialize(numbers)):    
    print("Factorial of", numbers[index], "is", fact)
```

It prints:

```
Factorial of 1 is 1
Factorial of 2 is 2
Factorial of 3 is 6
Factorial of 4 is 24
Factorial of 5 is 120
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fact = 1
for item in input_set:
    for number in range(1, item+1):
        fact = fact * number
    print "Factorial of", item, "is", fact
    fact = 1
```

Works as you need... Tested here[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php]

This should be your code. 
First, change your input_set to a list [] and not a dictionary.
Second, "input" is not a keyword that you have used, you have named it item.

Comment: You have also forgotten to reset the fact back to 1.
Hope this helps, ty

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset the factorial variable after an iteration.

```
input_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
for item in input_set:
    fact = 1
    for number in range(1,item+1):
    print fact
    print number
        fact = fact * number
    print ("Factorial of", item, "is", fact)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Its about your variable >>fact<< you placed in inside first for loop and your code is good.

> what happening here is your **fact=1** initialise value only once before entering loop while you need to do it each time out loop get execute.

```
input_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for item in input_set:
    fact = 1
    for number in range(1,item+1):
        fact = fact * number
    print ("Factorial of", item, "is", fact)
```

hope this helps and do little R&D on variable scope :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than it seems. You just need to place the fact/factorial variable inside the first loop. So that it gets reset every time the loop runs.

```
for number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
   factorial = 1
   for i in range(1, number + 1):
      factorial *= i
   print(f"Factorial of {number} is {factorial}")
```

Thanks, Ethan Lal